# how does energy exchange occurs without a matter exchange?

Tags: thermodynamics, matter

In thermodynamics, we differentiate between an open system( exchanging heat and matter with the surrounding), closed system(exchanging just heat), isolated system(neither both). My question is how is it possible to exchange heat without matter , taking into account that matter holds heat within it (is that right), so there is another thing that holds heat and is being exchanged , so what is this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever seen a Newton's cradle?

[image: Newton's cradle]

([image from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif))

This is an example of energy being transferred between the ends of a system without matter transfer. This is actually pretty close to what happens in thermodynamics systems. In most cases heat/internal energy is the energy of motion of molecules. Heat is transferred into the system when molecules outside it collide with the surface of the system and transfer some of their kinetic energy to the molecules inside it.

Comment: Thank u . At a quantum level , how do electrons ( in the case of collision) exchange energy? Do they change their state energy?

Comment: @ZaKh: The energy is simply the kinetic energy of the whole molecule i.e. one molecule simply bumps into another molecule and makes the second molecule move. Collisions between molecules don't involve excitations of the electrons unless the temperature is very high because at normal temperatures the collision energy is far below electron excitation energies.

Comment: Where does a molecule stores its energy?